# Munkres' Unit Circle Example - Topology on Domain

Tags: general-topology

Consider the $S^1 = \{ x \times y | x^2 + y^2=1 \}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $F:[0,1) \rightarrow S^1$ be defined by $t \mapsto (\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$. Will the inverse image of an open set containing $(1,0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ be open in $[0,1)$? I think this will be true regardless of whether I think of $[0,1)$ as the entire space with the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ or as a subspace topology on $\mathbb{R}$. I just want to make sure this is correct, because he doesn't specify what the topology should be on $[0,1)$.

Comment: [0,1) is presumed to have the subspace topology.  What is that pullback thing?  Is it the inverse image or some sort of kickback?

Comment: A subset of the form $[0,a)\cup(b,1)$ is open in  the space $[0,1)$ in the topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ but not in $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Sorry I was speaking informally, its the inverse Image, I've changed it

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales okay so for this map to be continuous, we should assume $[0,1)$ is in the subset topology then? Isn't that an important thing to state for this example? Was this an oversight -- or is it convention to assume an interval in \mathbb{R} is in the subspace topology unless otherwise stated?

Comment: Yes, that should have been made clear. I would have said something like "Is the inverse image open in $[0,1)$ *considered as a space*?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $[0,1)$ without further comments always means that it has the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R$. This agrees with metric topology on $[0,1)$ induced by the metric $d(x,y) = \lvert x - y \rvert$. Note that this metric is the restriction of the standard metric on $\mathbb R$.

Now you map $F$ is continuous because the two coordinate functions $\cos(2\pi t)$ and $\sin(2\pi t)$ are continuous. Hence preimages of open sets are open.